# Is there a switch to disable "cannot use temporary expression in write context" error?

Tags: php

The error was added in PHP7 and I have problem with such code as:

```
(some complex expression)->my_property = 1
```

*Please note I am assigning to the field of the object, not to the object itself (assigning to temporary object does not make sense, I agree, but here it is **not** the case).*

This gives me an error "cannot use temporary expression in write context". When I rewrite this as:

```
$tmp = (some complex expression);
$tmp->my_property = 1;
```

Everything is fine. The problem is I have to have single expression (assignment is an expression), and since PHP does not support comma operator now I am toasted with two **statements**.

For me this is huge difference, because I cannot pass entire code as an expression further. Everything is valid inside that "complex expression" so I would love to simply disable that check in PHP.

Is it possible? How?

*My code is written automatically (it is generated) and the outcome of the expression is a valid PHP object, the problem is PHP somehow does not notice it. Besides, the second form works.*

Update: this is an **example** of complex expression I mentioned above:

```
(($a = foo()) === 0 ? $a : bar())
```

Comment: what exactly is this complex expression returning/doing? given the error, you're trying to do something like `1 + 1 = 2`, which would try to assign `2` to the result of `1 + 1` - that'd be a temporary value, since it's not being stored anywhere, and you're attempting to write to it, causing the error.

Comment: @MarcB, I updated the question, your comparison is incorrect (a bit), because I am assigning some field, not the object. So even if the object is temporary, it is well known when it comes to accessing field, and it is the field which is assigned (altered), not entire object.

Comment: @MarcB The difference is that objects are passed around by reference, not by copying, so if an expression returns an object it's valid to assign to a property.

Comment: Can you post a slightly expanded example? While objects are passed around by reference, I'm failing to see how the example expression can reference a non-temporary object - so I'm obviously also missing something. (Side note, The complex expression doesn't work as if `foo() === 0` then `$a=0` and therefore you'll be assigning `0->my_property = 1`. But even correcting that to something "workable" I can't see how it's accessing a permanent object, so an expanded example might help.

Comment: @Robbie, more expanded example won't help here -- please see the last line of code I posted. `$a` is local variable, `bar()` could be a getter of global variable, or local one. It does not matter really, my point is, the expression is valid one, it produces valid object and assignment is also valid. However PHP has problems with it. As for side note -- you are correct, I just put it as an example, top from my head, to show something "complex" :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to say no.

> Everything is valid inside that "complex expression" so I would love to simply disable that check in PHP.

I think the issue here is that disallowing writing to temporary expressions is not simply a "check" in PHP but a part of the language as of 7.1 (introduced in [`5c2120b`](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/5c2120b6cf0d4a92a29dc7c38b407ee5ed213ddf)).

As of [`5c2120b`](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/5c2120b6cf0d4a92a29dc7c38b407ee5ed213ddf), the language grammar has been updated to redefine what is deferenceable as:

```
dereferencable:
        variable                { $$ = $1; }
    |   '(' expr ')'            { $$ = $2; zend_do_begin_variable_parse(TSRMLS_C); $$.EA = 0; }
    |   dereferencable_scalar   { $$ = $1; zend_do_begin_variable_parse(TSRMLS_C); $$.EA = 0; }
;
```

— [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5c2120b6cf0d4a92a29dc7c38b407ee5ed213ddf/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L1065-L1069)

Additionally, you'll notice that the sources of those errors in the codebase don't check anything before producing an error, e.g. [1](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/00e516e57549f29387ef858de7847e7e4ca0c1c0/Zend/zend_compile.c#L7963-L7966) and [2](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ae2f68d8a5868e90583765aca86c501f27664ef9/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L1905).

The workaround would be to downgrade to a version of PHP that allowed this.

Comment: Thank you, but "dereferencable" means I can write `a->b` when `a` is dereferencable. So I have expression as `a` (the second line). And this is correct, PHP complains about assignment, not dereference.

Comment: You would still need to dereference the temporary variable to be able to assign a value to it. That said, @NikiC might be able to shed more light on the change where it was their commit.

Answer (score 8):

I had this error come up while refactoring some badly written code:

```
class MyClass {

    static $cache = [];

    public function myFunction() {
            $this->cache['foo'] = 'bar';
    }
```

I rewrote this to fix the non-static reference to `$cache` inside `myFunction`:

```
class MyClass {

    static $cache = [];

    public function myFunction() {
            self::cache['foo'] = 'bar';
    }
```

Notice I missed the `$` and should have written `self::$cache['foo']`.

This produced the error `cannot use temporary expression in write context`, which wasn't particularly helpful. In my case there was nothing wrong with what I was trying to do, just simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to understand.
When you try to call Someclass::somevar, it means, that you'r trying to call "const" var from class, i.e constant variable, like "define()", but inside class. But when yor'r calling Someclass::$somevar, you'r calling "static" var, similar to object $someclass->somevar. 
This is just a very simple explanation for beginners or php-dummies.
For more understanding there is some examples http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: What question are you answering? I didn't eve use the syntax with "::" (static access).

Answer (score 0):

This is an assignment error.  You are running a statement like "(($a = foo()) === 0 ? $a : bar())" but the result isn't a class instance or variable.  It's just a random piece of code that ran.  That's why your second answer works because you are assigning the statement to the class $tmp.  Likewise when Henry used "self::cache['foo'] = 'bar';" that also was an assignment to a statement, not a member variable.  When he made it a variable the code worked.

If you want this on one line you would either have to keep with the original class $a and do $a->my_property = 1 or go with your second option and assign the code to a class object you create (`$tmp = (($a = foo()) === 0 ? $a : bar())->my_property = 1`).  This code also assumes $a has a public member "my_property".

Comment: Your terminology is very much imprecise -- there is no such such thing as `assignment to a statement` (just an example). LHS in my case is not random -- is is a valid object (type instance), temporary sure. But using `tmp` name and then ignoring it has exactly the same effect, it is still a temporary object, the fact I name it does not change a thing (except for the PHP interpreter that is).